# reading large json file in node JS

Tags: node.js

I am having 6GB of json file i need to read the entire file and transform into different JSON.Below is my Code.

```
var getStream = function () {
    var jsonData = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Search\\Json\\input1.json',
        stream = fs.createReadStream(jsonData, { encoding: 'utf8' }),
        parser = JSONStream.parse('*');
    return stream.pipe(parser);
};

let _factVlauesers =getStream()
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

       console.log(data);

       //  _factVlauesers = _preProcess.getRefMasterTemplate(_dataReaderJson.ref_factValues,data);

    }));
```

Very slow and Due async other codes are executed before reading the data.
Kindly give me some suggestion for reading a huge file in node JS
And another problem 
input json ex:

```
{"masters": [
        {
            "recordPguid": "urn:reference:1",
            "creationDate": "2020-04-24T05:19:12.295+0000",
            "lineage": "0000000140354986",
            "provenence": "LD9PA|006|2020",
            "usageRights": null,
            "itemStatus": 0,
            }]}
```

But parser it as

```
 { [
            {
                "recordPguid": "urn:reference:1",
                "creationDate": "2020-04-24T05:19:12.295+0000",
                "lineage": "0000000140354986",
                "provenence": "LD9PA|006|2020",
                "usageRights": null,
                "itemStatus": 0,
                }]}
```

It removes the master name .That important for me to iterate while transforming into some other JSON.

Comment: What is the issue you have here?

Comment: Out of memory exception. 6gb files has only one json Array i need to read that entire array

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: yeah i have done  fileStream.on('error', function (e,) {
        customError.streamException(e, `${_s3Details.s3.bucket.name}`, `${_s3Details.s3.object.key}`);
    }).pipe(JSONStream.parse("masters.*")).on('error', function (e) {
        customError.handleJsonStreamParserException(e, `${_s3Details.s3.bucket.name}`, `${_s3Details.s3.object.key}`);
    }).pipe(
        es.through(function (data) {
            count++;
            const beforeStream = Date.now();
            this.pause();
            processIntofile(data);
      
      
            return data;
        }).